# Using Fubini's theorem in proving a function is integrable.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, iterated-integrals

I am having a trouble with proving the following:
If $f : (0, a) → \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function and
        $$g(x) = \int_x^a \frac{f(t)}{t}dt$$
Then show that $g$ is intergrable and
$$\int_0^a g(t)dt= \int_0^a f(t) dt$$

For proving $g$ is integrable I have shown that $1/t$ is continuous in $(0,a)$ and $f$ being integrable $f(t)/t$ is integrable. However I am unable to come with an idea to show the second part, any suggestions? please help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\int_0^a \left(\int_x^a \frac{f(t)}{t} \, dt\right) \, dx = \int_0^a \left(\int_0^a \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathbf{1}_{t \geqslant x}\, dt\right) \, dx = \int_0^a\frac{f(t)}{t} \left(\int_0^a  \mathbf{1}_{x \leqslant t}\, dx\right) \, dt = \ldots$$

where $ \mathbf{1}_{t \geqslant x} = 1$ if $t \geqslant x$ and $ \mathbf{1}_{t \geqslant x} = 0$ if $t < x$ .

Comment: I am sorry that I don't understand how you changed the limits from x to a , as 0 to a

Comment: I included the indicator function which is $0$ when $0 \leqslant t < x$.  Fubinis theorem can be applied after changing to a rectangular domain.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^a  \mathbf{1}_{x \leqslant t}\, dx = \int_0^t dx= t$, so the RHS becomes $\int_0^a \frac{f(t)}{t}t \, dt = \int_0^a f(t) \, dt$

Comment: Just understand that $\int_x^a \frac{f(t)}{t} \, dt = \int_x^a \frac{f(t)}{t} \, dt + \int_0^x 0 \, dt = \int_0^a \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathbf{1}_{t \geqslant x}\, dt$.

Comment: Yeah, I do get it, the thing I am not having clarity is with ∫a01x⩽tdx=∫t0dx=t.

Comment: Now I do get it, Thank you for your suggestions. I am new to this, took some time to get it right.

Comment: why is ∫1x⩽tdx not equal to a-0=a ?

Comment: Guessing what you wrote, the integrand is an indicator function which is zero over part of the interval and 1 over the remainder.

Comment: I was asking why the region in which value of integrand is 1 is between 0 and t

Comment: We have $\int_0^a \mathbf{1}_{x \leqslant t} \, dx = \int_0^t  \mathbf{1}_{x \leqslant t} \, dx + \int_t^a  \mathbf{1}_{x \leqslant t} \, dx = \int_0^t  1 \, dx + \int_t^a  0 \, dx =  \int_0^t  1 \, dx = t-0 = t$

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way around? I mean isn't the indicator function = 1 between t and a

Comment: Indicator function depends on t and x , right ? So if I fix a t and integrate it with respect to x , then indicator function has value = 1 in whenever t<x, but I feel like this is outside the region we actually wants to integrate. I am unable to get a clear picture. thank you